# Tried the common methods to fix error too many redirects issue in wordpress but still no success

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

My wordpress developer and I tried the common methods but no success. I don't know else what to do.

Changed the WordPress URL settings, htaccess, wp-config and PHPMyAdmin but still "too many redirects"

Our  previous web developer ang fixed the error logs.

Our ssl cert of the website is set to to full and universal.

I was advised to check the DNS if it is pointed to the server you have.  Also, I should request to change the settings so we can just change the DNS.

Please assist me on what to do.

Here is my htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Do you have more directives in your `.htaccess` file? It is currently incomplete. What is the nature of redirect-loop? You need to check the network traffic and include this information in your question.

Comment: Please check the edited version ^ Thanks! :)